# Python Basics - Comparing 2 Arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I've been set the task to design a small game which includes a text file which is 'encrypted' and a 'decrypted' version of the text file. The user is shown the 'encrypted' list (which has been read in and appended to an array) with some clues e.g. A = # (I'm using a dictionary to store possible values of the symbols.)

My problem is: I have created the whole game but i have added an option to my menu to allow the End-User to compare the words they have substituted in with the 'decrypted' list (also read into an array) to see if they have completed the game.

I have tried the following code and have tested the game through to me being 100% sure the words were identical and the Python Shell printed "Sorry! Try Again!"

Here's The Code:

```
def compareFiles():
    for eachLine in range(len(rsef)):
        if rsef[eachLine] == rssf[eachLine]:
            print("Congratulations! Puzzle Solved!")
        else:
            print("Sorry! Try Again!")
            secMenu()
```

For Context:

secMenu() is my menu 
rsef is my 'encrypted' array 
rssf is the 'decrypted' array which i want to compare to.

EDIT:

```
Which Option Would You Like To Choose?
Option Number: 1
--------------------------------
1. View The Encrypted Words With Some Clues.

A+/084&"
A3MANA+
8N203:
,1$&
!-MN
.A7&33&
AMA71N
&-&641'2
A))85
9&330M
```

This is the Sorted List:

```
Which Option Would You Like To Choose?
Option Number: 5

ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

Comment: Does the order matter? Should each element of `rsef` be the same as the corresponding element in `rssf` or could they be in any order? Will the two arrays always be the same length?

Comment: Comparing lists in python is much easier, do `arr1[:] == arr2[:]`

Comment: note that the above code will print a 'pass' or 'fail' message for _every line_. you really want to collect an overall pass/fail for all lines and then print pass/fail.

Comment: Mr. E - Well the order is predefined, all the end-user can do is come up with values for the symbols. If it helps, each list has 10 Words.

Comment: You being sure doesn't help us. Print the lists and show us the output.

Comment: Pavel - Okay, yes i realized this question would probably need a lot of context.

Comment: For you all:

`Which Option Would You Like To Choose?
Option Number: 1

1. View The Encrypted Words With Some Clues.

A+/084&" 
A3MANA+ 
8N203:
,1$&
!-MN
.A7&33&
AMA71N
&-&641'2
A))85
9&330M`

Comment: Nothing there looks like two identical lists, or even like lists.

Comment: @PavelAnossov - Just edited the question, take a look.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza - what does the `:` do?

Comment: Okay, `ACQUIRED` certainly is not equal to `A+/084&"`.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman - Yes i wish for it to go line-by-line through the list and compare the words.

Comment: @PavelAnossov - I've added in the whole code (minus the menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's to check if all items in both lists are identical:

```
def compareFiles():
    if rsef == rssf:
        print("Congratulations! Puzzle Solved!")
    else:
        print("Sorry! Try Again!")
        secMenu()
```

If you insist on looping, the one below :)

```
def compareFiles():
    for eachLine in range(len(rsef)):
        if rsef[eachLine] != rssf[eachLine]:
            print("Sorry! Try Again!")
            secMenu()
            return 0 #exit the function, use this if you need it.

        print("Congratulations! Puzzle Solved!")
```

Comment: How could i change my code to check `eachLine` as i have already stated?

Comment: Hm.. What are you going to check? If both are similar?